# i want to draw continuous boxes in pine script with arrays

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

this is my code

```
    for bx in bullish_fvg_max
        box_left   = box.get_left(bx)
        box_top    = box.get_top(bx)      
        box_bottom = box.get_bottom(bx)

        box.delete(bx)
        array.set(bullish_fvg_max, array.indexof(bullish_fvg_max, bx),box.new(box_left, box_top, n, box_bottom , border_color = bull_fvg_css, bgcolor = bull_fvg_css,text = Btext, text_halign = text.align_right, text_valign = text.align_bottom))
        array.get(bullish_fvg_max, array.indexof(bullish_fvg_max, bx))
```

[image: error picture]

problem description:

i have many boxes in bullish_fvg_max, i want to continue the right side of boxes to the current bar, on every new bar(continuous boxes), i do get box coordinate and delete it and then set it's array value to the new value and called that array. but get that error when adding last line code(array.get)

Comment: is there any help!?

Comment: is there any help???????????